# Text mispositioned on some react cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that fetches videos, and it creates a card for each video that it fetches, on the card there is also the video title, video creator, video link, video download link, views, and the upload date.

I am fetching all of these things with no problems and they all display the way I want it to, for the most part.

The strange thing is for some cards, the text for download and view video is mispositioned, and is higher than it is supposed to be.

Here you can see the problem I'm experiencing, basically the first and third cards are displaying correctly but you can see that the middle card's text for download and view is higher for some reason.
[image]

the following is my css for the cards

```
.card {
    background-color: $secondaryColor;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    outline: black solid thin;
}

.authorInfo {
    display: flex;
}

.card-body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.card-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.watchComp {
    display: flex;
}

.dlComp {
    display: flex;
}

.card-deck {
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
```

the dl comp consists of the icon and the link, same with the watch comp. I have tried altering the positioning styling in the inspect element when this happens but nothing has worked.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? the cards I'm using is from react-bootstrap, if that matters.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the title being 1 text row instead of 2. The icons for "Watch Clip" and "Download Clip" look positioned based on the bottom of the white div. Try wrapping the icon and text in a div. And position this div how you want it (probably the same as the icons are positioned).

Comment: Ultimately, we can't help unless you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`Watch Clip` and `Download Clip` in the second screenshot snaps top because title has only one line `toxic`. You can wrap that row in a `<div>` tag or use `align-items: center` style.